# Stepwise Regression (direction = "both") in R

Tags: r, regression

I am trying to arrive at a final model using the stepwise regression function of R, starting with a set of 70 variables and a target, for some 50,000 observations.
Following is the call function I am running:

```r
glm_model <- glm(Target~.,data=base,family = "binomial")
step_model <- step(object = glm_model,direction = "both")
summary(step_model)
```

It takes a lot of time to execute, at least 16-20 hours. But, I have done the same step on the same dataset twice, and the results that I got has different set of variables. In the first run I got 21 variables, while on the second run I am getting a set of 25 variables. So, is it possible to get different results with each run while using the step function in R?

Comment: [Be very careful when using stepwise regression, or don't use it at all](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/179941/why-are-p-values-misleading-after-performing-a-stepwise-selection).

Comment: can you check it again, after set.seed(1) command? If you set seed, does step function yield different results each time?

Comment: Okay, I ran the same steps twice, however, in a subset of the data, with only 1000 observations, and I got the same models in both iterations.